# Custom test annotation not working in Quarkus

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, quarkus

I setup a multi-module project with quarkus, the core module contains custom test annotation like:

```
@QuarkusTest
@Tag("component")
@Documented
@Inherited
@Stereotype
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ComponentTest {
}
```

When I try to use this annotation on any class in another module(my-api) then it says -  javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: No bean found for required type of that Test class.

Quarkus version 2.14.2.Final

If I move this annotation to my-api module then it works fine.

Comment: Any chance you can share a sample application?

Comment: Works after adding jandex plugin https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/29829